# The file for the document x has been modified by another application. There are also unsaved changes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Starting with Xcode 13.1 I am getting quitte often an alert "The file for the document x has been modified by another application. There are also unsaved changes in Xcode". Quite often I am using Atom editor and Tower Git simultaneously with Xcode, so in the first place I thought that the incorrect update of one of the above was due to. My solution was to close those apps but still occasionally, the alert still pops up. Now I think the problem is Xcode 13.1, are there other people experiencing this behavior?

[image: Xcode 13.1 The file for the document x has been modified by another application. There are also unsaved changes in Xcode]

Comment: Sometimes when I use command-line git. Now Xcode really caches many things, even through launches. So you need to be careful - just keep in mind what and where you modify to do not loose changes.

Answer (score -1):

So the wording on these "modified from another application" popups is extremely sloppy and misleading.

In my case, I get this popup when I `git reset --hard HEAD` in the terminal.

It says:

```
The file “project.xcworkspace” has been modified by another application.

Do you want to keep the Xcode version, or use the version on disk?
```

When they say "Xcode Version" I often thought they meant "Xcode version" for example, Xcode 14.2.

However, they mean "the version of your project loaded into Xcode before another application tried to change it," a sort of "general" version of your project.

When they say "Version on Disk" I often was confused.  Are there cloud-based options, as opposed to what is on disk? It turns out what they mean is the version of your project the external application is attempting to change your project to.

So in the OP's case, "Keep Xcode Version" means "Keep the version of your project that is loaded into Xcode currently" OR "Revert" which means, change your project back to the version it was before the current version of your project loaded into Xcode.